# How to fix the position of a view inside a ViewPager and CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout, coordinator-layout

I have an activity with the layout of:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/indicator"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The fragment loaded in `ViewPager` has a layout of:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/download_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_download" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I fix the position (prevent scrolling) of the `FloatingActionButton` inside the fragment (it scrolls with its parent)?

Note that I couldn't move `FloatingActionButton` to the activity layout.

Comment: Why couldn't you move the FloatingActionButton to your activity layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a FAB in activity  layout. .If you need different colors or actions 
you can define FAB in your fragment and set the color or the action for each fragment.

Answer (score 10):

You should move your floating action button from your view pager to coordinator layout. From there you can set your floating action button position with

```
android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
```

or

```
app:layout_anchor="@id/yourViewToAnchor"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
```

And don't forget to put your floating action button on the lowermost of your coordinator layout XML to ensure that your floating action button at the top of your layout.